# Imprimir na tela lista dinâmica

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Pessoal não consigo realizar a função de imprimir na tela, poderiam me auxiliar nesta função abaixo.

```
void imprime_lista(Lista* li){
 while (li != NULL)
 {
    printf("%d ", li -> struct amatricula);
    li = li -> prox;
 }
 printf("\n");
}
```

As estruturas estão assim:

```
struct aluno {
  int matricula;
  char nome[30];
  float n1, n2, n3;
};
typedef struct elemento* Lista;

//Arquivo ListaDinEncad.c
struct elemento {
  struct aluno dadosAlunos;
  struct elemento *prox;
};
typedef struct elemento Elem;

Lista* criar_lista();
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
int varAux = 0;

struct aluno estruturaAlunoAuxiliar;
Lista *listaDeAlunos;

listaDeAlunos = criar_lista();

estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.matricula = 1;
strcpy(estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.nome, "Thiago Ferreira");
estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.n1 = 7;
estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.n2 = 6;
estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.n3 = 9;

varAux = inserir_no_inicio_da_lista (listaDeAlunos, estruturaAlunoAuxiliar);
//    varAux = imprime_lista(listaDeAlunos);
//printf("%d\n", varAux);
imprime_lista(listaDeAlunos);
return 0;
```

Comment: Eu imagino que tenha algum erro nas estruturas também, mas faz muito tempo que eu não crio uma lista em C e não vou lembrar.
Só que, pra imprimir algo no `imprime_lista`, eu imagino, tu deveria mudar de `li -> struct amatricula` para `li->dadosAluno.matricula`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o `dadosAluno` não é um ponteiro então é acedido com `.`.

A função de impressão deveria então ser:

```
void imprime_lista(Lista* li){
    while (li != NULL)
    {
        printf("Nome: %s ", li->dadosAluno.nome /*<--diferente aqui*/);
        li = li -> prox;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Repare que começou com `->` porque `li` é um ponteiro. Se não fosse(embora nestes casos é necessário que seja para que possa terminar em `NULL`) seria `li.dadosAluno.nome`.

Se o `dadosAluno` tivesse sido declarado como um ponteiro, assim:

```
struct elemento {
  struct aluno *dadosAlunos;
  struct elemento *prox;
};
```

Então o acesso na função já seria assim:

```
li->dadosAluno->nome
```

No entanto isto iria implicar alocar este objeto com `malloc` antes de utilizar e remover quando não fosse necessário com o `free`, o que iria complicar consideravelmente o código.

**Edit**:

O erro que lhe está a dar:

> request for member 'dadosAlunos' in something not a structure or union

Tem na verdade a ver com um erro subtil que tem no código, aqui:

```
void imprime_lista(Lista* /*<--aqui*/ li){
```

O parâmetro deve ser `Lista li`, e não `Lista* li` , pois `Lista` já é um `typedef` para um ponteiro, como pode ver aqui:

```
typedef struct elemento* Lista;
```

Logo estava a utilizar um ponteiro para um ponteiro! Como se fosse `struct elemento**`

**Edit 2**:

Assim como na minha ultima indicação, `Lista` já é um ponteiro para um nó da lista, logo não é suposto usar `Lista*` em nenhum lugar, a menos que seja como parâmetro de uma função que altera o inicio da lista.

Isto faz com que o seu `main` deva ser:

```
int main()
{
    int varAux = 0;

    struct aluno estruturaAlunoAuxiliar;
    Lista listaDeAlunos; //sem Lista* agora

    listaDeAlunos = criar_lista(); //este agora deve devolver um Lista e não Lista*

    estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.matricula = 1;
    strcpy(estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.nome, "Thiago Ferreira");
    estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.n1 = 7;
    estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.n2 = 6;
    estruturaAlunoAuxiliar.n3 = 9;

    //deve rever esta função pois ela para estar bem implementada deveria receber um 
    //Lista* para poder modificar o inicio da lista, o que faz com que deva ser passado o 
    //endereço da lista aqui no main
    varAux = inserir_no_inicio_da_lista (&listaDeAlunos, estruturaAlunoAuxiliar);

    imprime_lista(listaDeAlunos); //imprime agora recebe Lista e não Lista*

    return 0;
}
```

Terá agora que ajustar as respetivas funções para que coincidam com este novo `main` em termos de parâmetros e retornos.

Comment: Da erro: request for member 'dadosAlunos' in something not a structure or union|

Comment: Ele até compilou mas como ficaria na main: imprime_lista(listaDeAlunos);

Comment: @André Depende de como foi declarada a lista no `main`. Teria que ver essa parte do código

Comment: editei com a main que fiz

Comment: @André já editei a resposta para contemplar o seu `main` também

Comment: Ele dá um erro que o programa parou de funcionar. Mas chega imprimir sim.

Comment: @André isso já terá a ver com as outras funções todas que tem. Se não conseguir visualizar e/ou resolver esses problemas aconselho a abrir uma nova pergunta, pois já foge bastante à  que fez aqui

Comment: Vou realizar outra pergunta sobre inserção

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66610/discussion-between-andre-and-isac).